# How to inform prosecutors of potentially relevant information, and is it appropriate

Tags: evidence, florida

There is a somewhat well known streamer in a very small community, who has been well known in the community for making troubling claims, and generally giving the appearance of being, to some extent, mentally unwell.

This streamer never draws a crowd, and isn't famous as a streamer, but is rather well known in the community for his views and troubling behavior. He has had extreme anger fits on his stream when losing, has several guns and knives that he has shown on screen, and lives with his mother and has abused her constantly on stream.

Recently, something happened and he has been arrested, and is currently in jail awaiting arraignment. Aside from his charges, he seems to be undergoing some sort of mental health evaluation to determine if a 'risk protection order' should be applied. This is in Florida.

Several in the community feel previous clips from his stream should be made available to the prosecutors, showing he has a history of violence, such as cocking his gun and talking about finding and killing someone he had a disagreement with.

Is it appropriate for private citizens to make such information available to the police or prosecutors? If so, is emailing them from a provided contact address sufficient, or would something need to be filed in court?

Comment: Have to asked the investigating officer if this sort of material would be useful / relevant?

Comment: Is there any reason why you think the police and/or prosecutors are not savvy enough to figure this out for themselves?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't a party to the prosecution, so you can't file anything in court. You can call or write to the police or the prosecutor and provide them with whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Florida has a [TIPS line](http://myfloridalegal.com/__85256CC5006DFCC3.nsf/0/F8A5694BA199CD8585258611005A87E5?Open&Highlight=0,**tips) that allows you to provide anonymous information about crimes.